# How can I add a multi level extension to my OpenAPI class in java?

Tags: java, openapi

I am relatively new to OpenAPI 3, and could use a little guidance in how to make a multi level extension to my OpenAPI java class.

I need to make eg:

x-ibm-configuration:

```
testable: true
enforced: true
phase: realized
```

In my code, I can use `openAPI.addExtension("x-ibm-configuration", ???)` but how do I construct the object?

If you know any good OpenAPI java tutorials, that are a step beyond the basics, I am also interested.

Stay safe

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be as simple as creating a POJO. Next hurdle is getting the OpenAPI to not escape my multi line comments. But that's another issue.